# html5 drag & drop - TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple drag drop script. It basically lets me drag item from pane to another.

What wrong is when I finish dropping I got this error

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.
```

This is very weird because i'm pretty sure my argument is an object. So what I didn't get here?

Here is how the script look like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    ul,
    ol {
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 300px;
      float: left;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    ul {
      background: #927aff;
    }
    ol {
      background: #dda3f2;
    }
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      color: #fff;
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <ul id="music">
    <li draggable="true">pop</li>
    <li draggable="true">hiphop</li>
    <li draggable="true">jazz</li>
    <li draggable="true">country</li>
  </ul>

  <ol id="math">
    <li draggable="true">number</li>
    <li draggable="true">integeter</li>
    <li draggable="true">floating point</li>
  </ol>

  <script>
    var li = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(li, function(item) {
      item.ondragstart = function(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("secret", this);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById('math').ondrop = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('this', this);
      var dom = e.dataTransfer.getData("secret");
      console.log(dom);
      this.appendChild(dom);
    };
    document.getElementById('math').ondragover = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if the data as a part of the `dataTransfer` gets set as a string.

So the `dom` variable you have is a string, so it is not an HTML node that can be appended as a child

(this can all be seen if you add a breakpoint on exceptions)

---

Here is a working example (not using dataTransfer) that can work as a stepping off point: https://jsfiddle.net/maniator/aopmgvso/

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var currentDragging;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(li, function(item) {
  item.ondragstart = function(e) {
    currentDragging = this;
  }
});
document.getElementById('math').ondrop = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.appendChild(currentDragging);
};
document.getElementById('music').ondrop = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.currentTarget.appendChild(currentDragging);
};
document.getElementById('math').ondragover = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
document.getElementById('music').ondragover = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: the console.log(dom) does give me this '[object HTMLLIElement]' that's a string?

Comment: Which is a string :-)

Comment: how you make dataTransfer get set as an object?

Comment: You can't.... also you are setting it a billion time beforehand. one sec ill come up with a working example.

Comment: dataTransfer can only hold data -- like strings or integers.

Comment: well it works great in safari and chrome but firefox

Comment: What is the error? Look at the call stack. add a debugger. etc etc :-)

Comment: sorry. By not working, when drag, it doesn't move. But there is no error. Tested on FF 45

Comment: I dunno. Maybe ask a different question about it. Put debuggers everywhere :-)

Comment: I do not have firefox locally. sorry :-(

Comment: put this line in ondragstart event, it will work in firefox e.dataTransfer.setData("secret", 'dummy'); I edited the answer for you

Comment: @angry_kiwi please do not edit my answer with potentially wrong information. setData does not make it suddenly work in firefox... There must be something else that is going wrong in your code.

Comment: It's checked out. It's a known thing, FF requires data to be sent in order to create ghost image when dragging.

Answer (score 1):

dataTransfer is really meant for strings. What you can do is set a global array and pass the index to your DOM reference through dataTransfer.

Like so:

```
var ref = [];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(li, function(item) {
  item.ondragstart = function(e) {
    var index = ref.push(this) - 1; //as push() returns length, not index, remove 1.
    e.dataTransfer.setData("secret", index);
  }
});
document.getElementById('math').ondrop = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('this', this);
  var index = e.dataTransfer.getData("secret");
  dom = ref[index];
  ref = ref.splice(index, 1); //remove element at that index
  console.log(dom.innerHTML);
  this.appendChild(dom);
};
```

Or see example fiddle using your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ujv1uaLb/1/